# How do I see flows created by other accounts on a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow

I have been asked to add a simple workflow to a SharePoint list in M365. I can see the option for checking my flows but how can I quickly check if that list already has a flow created by another account? I understand there is an admin centre for flow but I don't currently have access to this.
Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet in a browser's developer console to get the list of flows associated with the SharePoint List using REST API. This will not provide the flows for a specified account, instead, it gives you all flows irrespective of accounts.

```
/* **** RUN THIS SNIPPET in Browser Developer Console to see the output **** */
// POST request Call
function RestRequest(url, params) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState != 4) // Loaded
                return;
            if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) {
                resolve(req);
            } else {
                reject({
                    status: req.status,
                    statusText: req.statusText
                });
            }

        };
        // Prepend web URL to url and remove duplicated slashes.
        var webBasedUrl = (_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "//" + url).replace(/\/{2,}/, "/");
        req.open("POST", webBasedUrl, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        req.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        req.setRequestHeader("x-requestdigest", _spPageContextInfo.formDigestValue);
        req.send(params ? JSON.stringify(params) : void 0);

    });

}

//Sends the post request and retrieves the Flow instances associated to SharePoint
RestRequest("/_api/web/GetList(@a1)/SyncFlowInstances?@a1='/sites/TeamSite/Lists/Clients'", null).then(function(resp) {
    var output = JSON.parse(resp.response);
    var flowinstances = JSON.parse(output.d.SynchronizationData).value;
    for (var i = 0; i < flowinstances.length; i++) {
        console.log('Name: ' + flowinstances[i].name + "\r\nDisplayName: " + flowinstances[i].properties.displayName + "\r\nEnvironment Name: " + flowinstances[i].properties.environment.name + "\r\nModified: " + flowinstances[i].properties.lastModifiedTime);       
    }
});
```

I hope this snippet will help you.